# How to add a text file or xml content to a TFS WorkItem description in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I want to add some description in a TFS Workitem using powershell.
I wrote following code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client")

    # Get TFS server and query from WIQ file
        [xml]$WiqlXML = Get-Content $WiqPath
        [String]$TFSservername = $WiqlXML | % {$_.WorkItemQuery.TeamFoundationServer} 
        [String]$queryString = $WiqlXML | % {$_.WorkItemQuery.Wiql}
$teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($TFSservername)

    # Get workitem collection from TFS Project
    $ws = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([type][Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
    $wis = $ws.Query($queryString);

    [Net.WebClient] $request =  New-Object Net.WebClient
    $request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
foreach($wi in $wis)
{
    $wi.Description += "`r`n========================================================"
    $wi.Description += "<xml>content</xml>"
}
```

But, in the workitem only **========================================================** is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your content is added, however as it is an HTML box it is not rendered and disappears.

You need to HTML encode your xml before adding it to the description field.